# Not calling onLeScan

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having trouble with calling my onLeScan. I placed a tag in my start scan and that gets called every time. For some reason my onLeScan never is getting called. Does anyone see an issue with what I have done? onLeScan should be called right after startLeScan, correct?

```
private void startScan() {
       Log.i(TAG, "Starting Scan");
       mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
       setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
       mHandler.postDelayed(mStopRunnable, 5000);
}

@Override
public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
    Log.i(TAG, "IN OnLeScan");
    Log.i(TAG, "New LE Device: " + device.getName() + " @ " + rssi);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            DeviceBeacon beacon = new DeviceBeacon(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), rssi);
            mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, 0, beacon));
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT** Changed up my onLeScan function. Still not working but I think I am going toward the right path. DeviceBeacon is a class that just includes methods: getName(), getSignal(), and getAddress()

**EDIT 2** I not sure where my error is. I have 2 nexus 7's I have both the bluetooth and bluetooth_admin permissions set along with the extra line to make sure I am only searching for bluetoothLE devices. startLeScan returns true. It is just not finding any devices in the area. Any reason why this may be? I even have both devices visibility set to true.

**EDIT 3** Git repo if you want to look at some of the code. 
https://github.com/cshunger/AndroidBluetoothTouch

**EDIT 4** My log cat:

```
01-12 01:18:59.728: I/BluetoothTouch(14510): Starting Scan
01-12 01:18:59.728: D/BluetoothAdapter(14510): startLeScan(): null
01-12 01:18:59.738: D/BluetoothAdapter(14510): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
01-12 01:19:04.763: I/BluetoothTouch(14510): Stoping Scan
01-12 01:19:04.763: D/BluetoothAdapter(14510): stopLeScan()
```

Comment: There are bunches of apps that aid BLE app development in the Play Store. You can use them to verify if you can scan/connect to peripherals.

Comment: They are both BLE devices and I have been able to scan for them and get their rssi values on other apps. I am trying to develop an app where I can do it.

Comment: In the first time, your log cat was shown exactly message `startLeScan(): null`. In the next time, it will scan exactly device. Make sure you are scanning Peripheral device, not mobile device.

Comment: I do not want to scan for peripheral devices though. I want to scan for mobile devices to just get their rssi values. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make both of your devices bluetooth discoverable.

Comment: Bluetooth is turned on with both devices and I have visibility set to on with both devices also. With BluetoothDevice.startLeScan() does this make it's own LE call to BluetoothDevice.startDiscovery()?

Comment: I ended up not using LeScan at all. I did not need it but it was crucial to make both devices discoverable. I ended up just using RSSI values without doing an LeScan.

Answer (score 1):

You need BOTH permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml in oder to scan for devices:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```